# Sending PHP JSON to Actions Script 3.0 text=Error #2032

Tags: php, actionscript-3, twitter-oauth

I seriously need help with Action Script 3.0 :S . The language is totally new to me.

I'm trying to send the `Abraham's Twitter OAuth` result from `PHP` to `AS3` and manipulated from there.

When my `PHP` echoes/sends the `OAUTH Twitter JSON` back to `AS3` I get this error:

> Error #2044: Unhandled ioError:. text=Error #2032: Stream Error. URL:
>   /my/php/link/here at AS3PHPTesting02_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()

What I'm trying to do is just to see the results in AS3.

What I used in`PHP: echo "returnData=".$result ;`

I used:  `var  jsonTwitter:JSON = e.target.data`  or `data.someparam

I hope someones could guide me. I know I'm doing something very dump.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That errors means you're not handling an [`IOErrorEvent`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/IOErrorEvent.html), which is dispatched generally when you're trying to load something that does not exist. For example, try run this and you'll get the same error:

```
var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("nonexistantfile.txt")
var ldr:URLLoader = new URLLoader(req);
```

You can avoid the error by attaching an event listener to the `URLLoader` that will manage an `IOErrorEvent`:

```
ldr.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, error);
function error(e:IOErrorEvent):void
{
    trace("There was an error!");
}
```

But the real problem you're having is that the path you're using in your `URLRequest` is incorrect.

Comment: Thank you so much for the handling part.  I've had a hard time figuring out the name of the event. For the request part it is working completely fine when I pass a regular string from php to as3 . But passing a php json object fires this error. Could the problem be with the json format? In php we will have stdclass object and stuff .

Comment: @iMohammad Having `returnData=` at the front of the output will make it invalid.